# Dynamic parameter replace single quot while replacing

Tags: java

I am replacing dynamic parameter using dynamic values of any string.

I have used below code :

```
public static String setDynamicParameter(String text,Object[] values){
    MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(text);
    return messageFormat.format(values); 
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    String text = "Test message 'test'";
    System.out.println(setDynamicParameter(text, null));
}
```

In the above code I am not using any dynamic parameter for test purpose.

```
OUTPUT : Test message test
```

What I am facing problem : It replace the single quot.

why it replaced single quot?

Comment: Because the quote is the escape character of MessageFormat. Just read its documentation. You need to double the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [`MessageFormat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a String.